# how to sset the default setting

Tags: javascript, html, css

i know this is very dumb question but i m stuck in this problem i create a form in jsp and in form i use a dropdown list which provide the option for change the css on Labels of form like ..."Left Align, Right Align, None" starting two optionare working properly "None" option  functionality is when i selected this option so the css which is applied by two option is removed and the default setting of this form is show............ please suggest me how i do it ...............here i m showing my code

**JavaScript Code**

```
function placement() {

    var dropVal = $('#styleField').val();
    if (dropVal == "la") {
        $("._check").each(function(index) {
            $('label').css("float", "left");
        });
    }
    if (dropVal == "ra") {
        $("._check").each(function(index) {
            $('label').css("float", "right");
        });
    }
    if (dropVal == "de") {
        //      $("._check").each(function(index) {
        //                              $('._check').find('checkbox').css("float" , "left")
        //  $("float").remove();
    });
}
}
```

this is my code and _check is a class which is applied on checkbox

**Html Code**

```
<select id="styleField" name="styleOfField" class="form-control select2me" data-placeholder="Placement Of labels" onclick="placement();">
 <option> - </option>
 <option value="la"> Left Aligned </option>
 <option value="ra"> Right Aligned </option>
 <option value="de"> Default  </option>
</select>
```

so please help me ...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset the float, you want to set `float: none`:

```
$('label').css('float','none');
```

But your code has other issues. You are iterating through each `_check` for no apparent reason. `$('label')` will target all labels, regardless of the presence of any `._check` element.

Are you looking for `label` inside a `._check` element? In that case, you can select them with the descendant selector, , and you don't need to iterate over the results, `.css` works across entire sets:

```
$('._check label').css('float','none');
```

You appear to have two options for the default behavior. One which has the value `"de"`, and one which doesn't have a value at all. The latter will not match any condition in your `placement` function.

Furthermore, the code you've shown us has unmatched brackets, but I suppose that may just be a pasting issue.

---

You could also do this with classess. That way you don't have to manually set `float: none`, but you could simply omit setting a float when none is needed.

**CSS**

```
.la { float: left; }
.ra { float: right; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
function placement() {
   $('._check label')
       .removeClass('la ra')
       .addClass($('#styleField').val());
}
```

---

Some notes on your commented out attempts:

- `$('._check').find('checkbox')` would look for all `<checkbox/>` children of a `class="check"` element. If you want to search for an `<input type="checkbox" />` you may use the `:checkbox` selector.
- `$('float').remove()` would look for all `<float/>` elements in the document and remove them.

---

**Update addressing your comment**

Now that you've clarified that you want all labels with a `_check` class, my code above doesn't do that. It selects all labels that are the *descendants* of an element with a check class. *Your* code selects all labels regardless of whether they have a check class, and does so repeatedly because of your iteration.

If you truly want all labels in the document that has a class named `_check`, the code would be:

```
 $('label._check').css('float','none');
```

Comment: i iterating becoz i want all the labels which have  _check class..... anyway thanks "float" - none is worked (y)...

Comment: i want top and down option also in my dropdown list so which functionality i use for this option working ???

Comment: Your code still doesn't do that. `$('label').css(...)` will set the css for *all* labels in the document. The fact that you're doing that within a `$('._check').each(...)` doesn't change that. It only means that you're setting the float for labels to a given value several times consecutively. Your iterations can be removed entirely and you will have the exact same functionality (although it will still not be what you asked for, which I'm addressing in the edit to my question)

Comment: For vertical alignment, you want to set the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property. Note that this is more closely related to `text-align` than to `float` in terms of behavior.